# Send sms pending intent extras get overide

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

Hi I'm sending messsage from my app through SmsManager in my service and register broadcast receivers for sms sent and delivered where I want to update message status as it is reached or not. As per now I'm able to send messages by putting extras with row id in Pending Intent with flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`. But once messages is send I'm receiving broadcast events with extras of last row only and I'm not able to retrieve extras of other rows. I'm using PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT that is why  extras are getting override and I have checked other flags also but of no use. How to get extras of other rows also without being override? and one more thing I am sending sms in service is this approach  proper? Any suggestions will be
of great help.

```
  String mSelectionClause = MyContentprovider.STATUS+ " = ?";
                 String[] mSelectionArgs = {"fail"};


                    Uri students = MyContentprovider.CONTENT_URI_SENDMSG;
                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(students, null, mSelectionClause, mSelectionArgs, "userphno");
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                       do{



                               String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
                                String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

                                Intent SENTINTENT=new Intent(SENT);
                                SENTINTENT.putExtra("id",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( MyContentprovider._ID)));
                                SENTINTENT.putExtra("userno", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( MyContentprovider.USER_PHNO)));
                            if(c.isLast()){

                                SENTINTENT.putExtra("lastrow", "true");

                            }


                                Intent DELIVEREDINTENT=new Intent(DELIVERED);
                                DELIVEREDINTENT.putExtra("id",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( MyContentprovider._ID)));
                                DELIVEREDINTENT.putExtra("userno", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( MyContentprovider.USER_PHNO)));

                                  PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                                          SENTINTENT, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                                  PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                                          DELIVEREDINTENT, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                                  String msg= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( MyContentprovider.MESSAGE));

                       SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                                      sms.sendTextMessage( c.getString(c.getColumnIndex( MyContentprovider.USER_PHNO)), null, msg, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

and in broadcast receiver and I am  storing the ids of row nothing much code there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I found is to pass a unique `int` for the `requestCode` (the second argument) in:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, SENTINTENT, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Then it creates a new `PendingIntent` for each.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to use

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
```

instead of

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

at both places

`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` will replace the existing pending intent with new extra data

Comment: let me check that one

Comment: hai i used PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT but i am getting null pointer exception while retrieving extras